# Why lsmod command does not list modules loaded by Xorg?

Tags: module, linux-kernel, kernel, x11, xorg

As in title why lsmod does not list modules like extmod, dri, dbe... loaded by default by Xorg?

Comment: This is clearly not a programming question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Xorg modules you list, are not kernel modules. They are specific to Xorg. Xorg may benefit from some kernel modules through.

You can see the loaded modules from the Xorg log using

```
grep LoadModule /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

Answer (score 1):

It loads only one module (If not already loaded). And that is your Display Driver.
(NV/NVIDIA/NOUVEAU or any Intel/AMD drivers)